# Call to a member function editions() on null

Tags: laravel

```
// Database Seeder
$book = Book::where('book_title', 'Harry Potter')->first();
$book->editions()->create([
     'image_url' => 'https://url.jpg',
     'publisher' => 'Scholastic Inc.',
     'edition_year' => 2003,            
     'pages' => 309,
     'cover_type' => 'HC',
]);
```

```
// Book Model
    public function editions() {
        return $this->hasMany(Edition::class);
    }
```

I'm trying to add a book edition to a book (one-to-many), but it returns "Call to a member function editions() on null".

What am I doing wrong? I'm new to Laravel.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  The error indicates `$book` equals `null`. It is possible when your query `Book::where(...)->first()` returns no result. Maybe you don't have a book titled "Harry Potter" in the database?

Comment: Just right above I have ```Book::create(['book_title' => 'Harry Potter' ....])```, so that's not the problem. I checked in the database, it's there as well.

Comment: That's weird. In any case, `$book` happened to be `null` for some reason, and has nothing to do with `editions()` method.